# Are there any differences between Shimano 10-speed connecting pins?

Tags: chain, shimano

I am looking for connecting pins for Shimano CN-5600 and CN-5701. I found some on [eBay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xshimano%2010%20connecting%20pin.TRS0&_nkw=shimano%2010%20connecting%20pin&_sacat=0) but are for Dura Ace. Are they compatible?

The chains in question are super narrow HG which are 5.88 mm wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, despite other differences between chain models (directional vs not, IG vs HG, etc), there is only one model of Shimano replacement pin for each speed generation of Shimano chain.